# ASP.NET MVC - T4 MVC - POST with Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("items")]
public partial class ItemsController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var model = new MyApp.Models.Items();
    return View(model);
  }

  // POST: /items/delete
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("delete")]
  public ActionResult Delete(DeleteItemModel model)
  {
    // delete the item
    model.Delete();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
}
```

In my Index.cshtml, I have the following:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Items

<h2>Hello</h2>
<form action="@Url.Action(MVC.Items.Delete())" method="post">
  <button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
```

The above is clearly a subset of my view. My main concern is, how to pass a `DeleteItemModel` from my `form` back to the `Delete` action. What am I missing? The MVC.Items.Delete path was generated from T4MVC. Yet, I can't figure out how to pass a model into it. Is there a fix here, or do I have to use some other approach entirely?

Comment: what are your fileds in your form? the names of the form elements must be the same name as the property names of DeleteItemModel class

Comment: The names of the form elements match the property names. The problem is the constructor generated by T4MVC.  The constructor expects a `DeleteItemModel` However, one isn't available in the razor view.

Comment: where is your constructor code? you have not posted here. When you submit the form(Items/delete), the Delete action is invoked and the data would be bound automatically. wt is not happening?

Comment: @KarthikMR The MVC.Items.Delete method is generated by T4MVC. I need one that accepts a Model. Or, a work around.

Comment: Could you post the code for your `DeleteItemModel` class? Also, does `MyApp.Models.Items` _contain_ any `DeleteItemModel`s? (I'm assuming not, but wanted to check.)